# 400 Bad Request in my woocommerce-api ionic 3 application

Tags: ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

I just installed woocommerce-api, created new api keys (api is enabled) in woocommerce and did a simple call to get products and test it in my ionic 3 application,
but I'm getting this -1 (400 Bad request) error

this is my code

```
WooCommerce: any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController)
{this.WooCommerce = WC({
url: "http://localhost/wordpress/index.php",
consumerKey: "ck_d165ee6b1c1f85fc17f5a615a9a630f6d7fb086a",
consumerSecret:"cs_a1c208feeb9d9aec03acfdc50cef20ae93294f7a",
wp_api:true,
version:'wc/v3',
});
this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products").then( (data) => {
console.log(data);
},
(err) => {
console.log(err) })}
```

any help?

Comment: any one? please i am stuck

Answer (score 0):

Please remove two lines from WC parameter

```
wp_api:true,
version:'wc/v3',
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
wpAPI: true,
version: 'wc/v2',
queryStringAuth: true,
```